# Inside of 2.4 GHz Dipole Antenna

Tags: rf, antenna, wireless, nrf24l01, balun

I bought the following dipole antenna:

### [image]

Now I want to add some extra simple reflector and directors next to this dipole to construct a Yagi-Uda antenna. For this aim, I need to know where is its feeding point (its center for a dipole antenna ). Eventualy I removed the cover of the antenna as follows:

[image]

My question is that where is the feeding point of this antenna In this last figure? Is it as in the following figure? If it's not, could you show it?
[image]

By the way, the antenna link is here : [with an NRF24L01 Module](https://www.banggood.com/1100-Meter-Long-Distance-NRF24L01PALNA-Wireless-Module-With-Antenna-p-1057170.html?rmmds=search&cur_warehouse=CN)

Comment: You would be better off using a reflector like http://www.freeantennas.com/projects/template2/index.html

Comment: See http://save.sys.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~takei/rengou/program/pdf/10-2A-01.pdf . The dimensions and spacing of the parasitic elements would need to be scaled to your frequency. Be aware that gain is increased in the direction of the main lobe, but decreased in other directions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a quarter wave monopole antenna and it is end fed by an unbalanced coax feed from an unbalanced (ground referenced) source. It's not a half wave dipole (balanced centre-fed) so it won't make a good choice for a Yagi antenna.